# How to create a Facebook-like tool tip layout using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use twitter bootstrap to create Facebook like tooltip layout.

I would really appreciate if someone could let me know how can I use twitter bootstrap to create this layout, I don't need it as tooltip, I need it in regular div.

I've attached picture the represent what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: This really has little to do with Twitter Bootstrap. You'll have to do the CSS/HTML for this yourself.

Comment: I thought it might be easier to implement it using their pre configured css definitions. thanks.

Comment: not tooltip and not popover, just this layout inside regular div

Comment: we need more information. width/height/position. That format can easily be done with the twitters grid system, but we don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi, The big pictures are 96x96, the small ones are 32x32. Thanks Andres! :-)

Comment: @liorix just saw your comment, was not paged when you posted. Gave my answer down below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's my take on that box using the twitter bootstrap framework. Had to modify some span widths in order to conform to your image sizes but i used an id to target them so they won't bother other `span*` classes throughout your page design.

I put it up on a jsFiddle since its quite a bit of code so check it out: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ4GB/show/) here, edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ4GB/).

**CSS:**

```css
body {
    margin:50px;
}

#box {
    border: 1px solid #92959C;
    width:290px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #ccc;

}

#box .row {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#box [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#box .span0 {
    width:32px;
    margin-left:1px;
}

#box li.span0:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

#box .span1 {
    width: 96px;
}

#box .span2 {
    width:165px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

#box .span2 p, .span2 a {
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0;
}

#box .span2 h4 {
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:10px;
}

#box .span1 img {
    width:96px;
    height:96px;
}

#box .img-list {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#box-footer {
    margin-top:10px;
    width:290px;
    border-top:1px solid #aaa;
}

.gray {
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    padding:10px 10px 20px;
    min-height:20px;
}
​
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="box" class="span4">
            <div class="span1">
                 <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/96x96">
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <h4>Omer</h4>
                <p class="muted">AI Lead at New brand analytics</p>
                <a href="#">64 mutual friends</a>
                <ul class="img-list">
                    <li class="span0">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/32x32">
                    </li>
                    <li class="span0">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/32x32">
                    </li>
                    <li class="span0">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/32x32">
                    </li>
                    <li class="span0">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/32x32">
                    </li>
                    <li class="span0">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/32x32">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="box-footer" class="span4">
                    <div class="gray">
                        <a href="#" class="btn pull-right">Friends</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Wow, after doing all of that work, you deserve an upvote. Also, in the spirit of SO, I think the important sections of the code deserve to be inlined in your answer.

Comment: I'm really impressed! Thanks!! :-)

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, i kind of thought it was too much, but it fits in nicely, i'll keep it in mind when posting.

Comment: @Andres, whoah! I'll give you 1 bottle of energy drink for that. If only I could. Anyhow, I learned a new tip from this answer.